# R: GGPlot Multiple Boxplots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to plot four boxplots in one chart, however i want to add the median and range myself.

My code

```
ggplot(data = df_subset[df, aes(y = target_fed_funds_rate_median, x = Date, group = Date)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(ymin = target_fed_funds_rate_lr, lower = target_fed_funds_rate_cl, middle = target_fed_funds_rate_median,
    upper = target_fed_funds_rate_ch, ymax = target_fed_funds_rate_hr))
```

generates the following chart: [What my code is generating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiFLi.png)

However, I am looking to create a chart similar to this one: [How my chart should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwXXb.png)

What my Dataframe looks like: [my dataframe df:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxJ90.png)

Any ideas how to fix this? Many thanks

Below a reproducable example:

```
time = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
median = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
low = c(0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5)
high = c(1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5)
center_high = c(1.25, 2.25, 3.25, 4.25, 5.25)
center_low = c(0.75, 1.75, 2.75, 3.75, 4.75)

df = data.frame(median, low, high, center_high, center_low)

ggplot(data = df, aes(y = median, x = time, group = time)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(ymin = low, lower = center_low, middle = median,
    upper = center_high, ymax = high))
```

Any ideas how to fix this? Many thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO, TRV! It would be easier to help you if you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data. To share your data, you could type `dput(NAME_OF_DATASET)` into the console and copy & paste the output starting with `structure(....` into your post.  If your dataset has a lot of observations you could do e.g. `dput(head(NAME_OF_DATASET, 10))` for the first ten rows of data.

Comment: brilliant thanks, will add this in a bit!

Comment: @stefan, is this what you had in mind?

Comment: Not a `dput()` but providing your example data this way is also fine or even  better. (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you want to "manually" create a boxplot by providing the boxplot stats you have to set `stat="identity"` in `geom_boxplot`:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = df, aes(y = median, x = time, group = time)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(
    ymin = low, lower = center_low, middle = median,
    upper = center_high, ymax = high
  ), stat = "identity")
```

[image]